# I need a code to take the input from dropdown menu and gives the output as an image using HTML and Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I am new to HTML and Javascript. I want to change the input text and show image when user selects an option from dropdown. From one function getname, I have got the changing text part working, but I am unable to get image as output.

```
 <HTML>
        <Head>
        <Title>Hi</Title>

        <H1>Hi</H1>
        </head>
        <body>


        <select name="dropdown" id="dropdown">
          <option value="Maruti">Maruti</option>
          <option value="Tata">Tata</option>
          <option value="Mahindra">Mahindra</option>
          <option value="Fiat">Fiat</option>

        </select>

        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" onClick="getName()">

        <script>
        function getName(){
        var select = document.getElementById('dropdown');
        var input = document.getElementById('name');
        select.onchange = function() {
            input.value = select.value;
        }

        function getImage(){
        var img = document.getElementById('dropdown');
        if (img.value=="Tata"){
        show_image("Tata.bmp", 276, 110);
        }
        else
        {if (img.value=="Maruti"){
        show_image("Maruti.bmp", 276, 110);
        }
        else
        {if (img.value=="Mahindra"){
        show_image("Mahindra.bmp", 276, 110);
        }
        else
        {if (img.value=="Fiat"){
        show_image("Fiat.bmp", 276, 110);
        }
        }
        }
        }
        }
        </script>

        </body>

        </HTML>
```

Thanks

Comment: you are writing multiple else.Change it to elseif and last one to else.

Answer (score 0):

One way is you create an img tag and place the image there when user selects option from dropdown. Here is working updated code,

```
<HTML>
<Head>
  <Title>Hi</Title>
  <H1>Hi</H1>
</head>

<body>

<select name="dropdown" id="dropdown">
  <option value="Maruti">Maruti</option>
  <option value="Tata">Tata</option>
  <option value="Mahindra">Mahindra</option>
  <option value="Fiat">Fiat</option>
</select>

<input type="text" name="name" id="name" />
<img id="imgHere" src="" />

<script>
function getName(){
    var select = document.getElementById('dropdown');
    var input = document.getElementById('name');
    select.onchange = function() {
        input.value = select.value;
        getImage();
    }
}

function getImage(){
    var img = document.getElementById('dropdown');
    var imgTag = document.getElementById('imgHere');
    if (img.value=="Tata"){
        imgTag.src = "1.png";
    } else if (img.value=="Maruti"){
        imgTag.src = "2.png";
    } else if (img.value=="Mahindra"){
        imgTag.src = "3.png";
    } else if (img.value=="Fiat"){
        imgTag.src = "Fiat.bmp";
    }
}

window.onload = getName;
</script>

</body>
```

Comment: do you have the images "Tata.bmp", etc. in the same directory as this file?

Comment: yes.... I am doing it on Notepad++ and running it in chrome. Is there any setting that I have to change before execution. But it other codes are working fine.

Comment: Ok i have updated again, and tested as well this time. Just make sure you replace the image file names (1.png etc.) with yours.